# What is the proper way to export Azure SQL DB to Blob using SAS?

Tags: azure, azure-cli

When I repeat steps from here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/sql/db?view=azure-cli-latest#az-sql-db-export

`StorageAccessKey` works fine.

`SharedAccessKey` is failing with:

> Operation failed with status: 'Bad Request'. Details: There was an
>   error that occurred during this operation : 'Error
>   encountered during the service operation. ; Exception
>   Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Dac.Services.ServiceException:Unexpected
>   exception encountered while retrieving metadata for blob
>   &#39;https://satest.blob.core.windows.net/backup/mydb-2019-5-13-10-1.bacpac&#39;.;
>   Inner exception Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.StorageException:The
>   remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden.; Inner exception
>   System.Net.WebException:The remote server returned an error: (403)
>   Forbidden.; '

What am I missing?

Comment: how did you get the `SharedAccessKey`?

Comment: As documentation suggest: az storage blob generate-sas --account-name myAccountName -c myContainer -n myBacpac.bacpac \
                            --permissions w --expiry 2020-01-01T00:00:00Z

Comment: Try to generate SAS token in your storage account -> `Shared access signature`  in the portal, will it work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Dac.Services.ServiceException:**Unexpected
>   exception encountered while retrieving metadata for blob**

From the error message, it looks like you need `read` permission as well in your `Shared Access Signature (SAS)`. Please regenerate SAS with both `read` and `write` permission.

```
az storage blob generate-sas --account-name myAccountName -c myContainer -n myBacpac.bacpac \ --permissions rw --expiry 2020-01-01T00:00:00Z
```

Comment: Yes it works now, I noticed comment in feedback section: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/sql/db?view=azure-cli-latest#feedback